# How to select AVG in dql?

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I want to  get avg of a column in dql but i got no luck.

```
    $qb = $this->em->getRepository($this->target)->createQueryBuilder('m');         
    $qb
        ->select($qb->expr()->avg('m.total_online as ACU'))
        ->where('m.server = :server')
        ->andWhere('m.time LIKE :time')
        ->setParameter('server', $server)
        ->setParameter('time',$date.'%');           
        $rs= $qb->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

But it won't give me the result as i expected:

```
+--------+
| ACU    |
+--------+
| 0.1429 |
+--------+
```

My sql is:

```
SELECT AVG(Total_Online) as ACU FROM `monitor` WHERE time like '2016-12-01%' AND server='$x'
```

Could some one help me??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer here:

```
$qb = $this->em->createQueryBuilder();
$rs = $qb
        ->select($qb->expr()->avg('m.total_online'))
        ->from($this->target,'m')
        ->where('m.server = :server')
        ->andWhere('m.time LIKE :time')
        ->setParameter('server', $server)
        ->setParameter('time',$date.'%')            
        ->getQuery()
        ->getResult();
```

Hope it will be helpful for someone.